# I have a problem with javascript $ .get (URL, callback);

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

*Thanks for the support!* - *Sory, my english is bad!*

I use this code to get the DOM component from the page entry to display on the homepage.
When I click on `open-ajax`, it loads the DOM from the entrypage and display in `ajax-outer`, when clicked on `ajax-overlay`, it will delete the DOM.

But I discovered an error, if I clicked on an open-ajax link and clicked on `ajax-overlay` immediately, `get ()` will still load the DOM and display in `ajax-outer`.

It seems that `ajax-overlay` is unable to stop `get ()`
How can I optimize the code?

**Html from Homepage:**

```
<div class="main_content">
   <a class="open-ajax" href="/link/101">1</a>
   ...
   <a class="open-ajax" href="/link/10n">n</a>
</div>
<div class="ajax-wrap">
   <div class="ajax-overlay"></div>
   <div class="ajax-outer"></div>
</div>
```

**Html from Entry:**

```
<div class="coupon_content">
   <div class="abc">
   ....
   </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('.main_content').on('click', '.open-ajax', function(e) {
    var gethref = $(this).attr('href');
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.ajax-wrap').addClass('active');
    $.get(gethref, function(sch) {
        $('.coupon_content', sch).each(function() {
            $('.ajax-outer').append($(this).html());
            $("body").addClass('noscroll');
        });
    });
});

$('.ajax-overlay').click(function(e) {
    $('.ajax-wrap').removeClass('active');
    $('.ajax-outer').children().remove();
    $("body").removeClass('noscroll');
});
```

Ví dụ tương tự : https://dribbble.com/shots

Comment: You could use a variable; clicking on `open-ajax` sets it to true, clicking on `ajax-overlay` sets it to false. In the `$.get` success callback, check the variable first. Edit: one second later, madalinivascu posted it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't prevent a ajax request but you can prevent the appending using a global variable

```
var canAppend = true;
$('.main_content').on('click', '.open-ajax', function(e) {
    var gethref = $(this).attr('href');
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.ajax-wrap').addClass('active');
    $.get(gethref, function(sch) {
        if(canAppend) {
        $('.coupon_content', sch).each(function() {
            $('.ajax-outer').append($(this).html());
            $("body").addClass('noscroll');
             canAppend = true;
        });
        }
    });
});

$('.ajax-overlay').click(function(e) {
    $('.ajax-wrap').removeClass('active');
    $('.ajax-outer').children().remove();
    $("body").removeClass('noscroll');
    canAppend = false;
});
```

Comment: It only runs for the first time: ((

Answer (score 1):

You could hide the `ajax-overlay` when you click `open-ajax` and show it in the success callback, this way you make sure that the overlay will not be clicked until all the code is loaded:

```
$('.main_content').on('click', '.open-ajax', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var gethref = $(this).attr('href');
    $('.ajax-wrap').addClass('active');

    $('.ajax-overlay').hide();

    $.get(gethref, function(sch) {
        $('.coupon_content', sch).each(function() {
            $('.ajax-outer').append($(this).html());
            $("body").addClass('noscroll');

            $('.ajax-overlay').show();
        });
    });
});
```